# How can I prevent echoes from a video inserted into Microsoft PowerPoint 2010?

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

When I insert a video (`WMV`) into a PowerPoint 2010 presentation and play the presentation back the video has a bad echo but the rest of my presentation is fine where I do a voice over.

How can I stop the echoes?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me and for some reason the video had been inserted twice. So two videos were playing at the same time and making the powerpoint echo. Just click on the video in the slide edit mode and delete it, there should be another hidden directly beneath it.